# cusom stories with custom properties

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to understand how to post a custom story with dynamic properties without app's server. At the moment, we have a server, that returns an object,s html dynamicaly, according passed parameters. But in fact, that means that created in FB app's setting object is never used:

```
   FB.api(
  'me/apitestingnamespace:found',
  'post',
  {
    'testing_object': '"our_server_url_with_parameters_for_object_here"'
  },

 function(response) {
    // handle the response
  }
);
```

But an object's settings you CAN add your custom parameters. Code, given by FB, contains some default set of parameters (http://samples.ogp.me/793672427425870). How can I change them?

I'v tried to find any information on FB docs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph). Any example/advice/link?

Comment: I guess, I can place my own htmls with properties somewhere on static server. but in this case I will not be able to change any properties in it

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more what you are trying to do? What do you mean with "dynamic" properties? Why don't you want to use your own server to host the OG objects?

Comment: Sorry, I'v worked it out a long ago. Just postet my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I found, that we are able to pass as object not an UTL, but the object itself:

```
var requestData = {};
var objectProperties =
{
    app_id: "123456789",
    title: "object title",
    image: imageUrl,
    type: applicationNamespace + ":" + objectType
};
requestData[objectType] = objectProperties;

FB.api(
    'me/' + applicationNamespace + ':' + action,
    'post',
    requestData,
    function(response)
    {

    }
);
```

so, you can easely manage any story-object properties at the clint-side: how many score did user get, how manny levels complete, etc.